# Carousel doesn't work in latest Bootstrap's versions

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, carousel, bootstrap-5

I've been trying to make a simple carousel but for some reason can't get it working. I tried using only sample code provided by Bootstrap's docs, and even so it doesn't work as intended. (Slides won't pass and next/previous buttons don't work)

Using much older versions of Bootstrap's JS from the CDN worked, but when using Bootstrap 4.5+ it just won't work properly.

Here's the code (which pretty much everything is from the docs):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/carousel1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/carousel2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/carousel3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have simply made a typo in your data attribute names.
Your code works after changing this:
`data-slide="prev"` and `data-slide="next"`
to this:
`data-bs-slide="prev"` and `data-bs-slide="next"`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png?text=carousel1" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png?text=carousel2" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png?text=carousel3" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>


</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```